# Object of type 'BeautifulSoup' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, html

I am trying to  load html content to confluence page .I am trying to use BeautifulSoup pkg to achieve this . In that process i am getting below error. is there any way to resolve these issue or any other appraoch to achieve this task.

> **TypeError: Object of type 'BeautifulSoup' is not JSON serializable**

below is the content of html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.
  <br>This is going < ,= to print
This is going >  to print</br>
```

code:

```
import yaml
from atlassian import Confluence
import urllib, mimetypes
import  requests
import codecs,json

confluence = Confluence(
    url='https://confluence.com',
    username='12344',  # of system where this page would open
    password='abcd')

####reading HTML file
with open("sample.html", 'r')as f
content = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')


# Create page from scratch
status = confluence.create_page('ABCD' ,#space,
                       'Report',#title
                        soup ,#'This is the body',#body,
                       parent_id=123456,### this is the pageid of the page under which new page will be created
                       type='page',
                       representation='storage',
                       editor='v2')

print(status)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
status = confluence.create_page('ABCD' ,#space,
                       'Report',#title
                        soup ,#'This is the body',#body,
                       parent_id=123456,### this is the pageid of the page under which new page will be created
                       type='page',
                       representation='editor')
```

using this we can achieve this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).